# How to loop through array of strings Python

Tags: python-2.7

in order to execute this code, which basically deletes a word from a sentence, we have to use split.string in order to access words.

```
 def censor(text, word):
     splitstring=text.split()
     for elem in range(len(splitstring)):
        if splitstring[elem]==word:
             splitstring[elem]='*'*len(word)

    return " ".join(splitstring)**strong text**
```

why can't we use use a "traditional" for-loop, as if looping through a word for a letter?

```
for word in text:
    for elem in word:
        if elem==word:
             word='*'*len(word)    """etc"""
```

Comment: Because without splitting, `for word in text` assigns `word` to each *character* in `text`. Presumably you want to delete whole words, not just any character that happens to appear in that word. But why ask here; why not try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple questions here:

1. When we iterate over a string of text, why do we get individual letters not words ?
   The Zen of Python states "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."
   A string is a just *string* of characters. It may or may not have individual words in it. The most obvious way to iterate over a string is one character at a time.
2. When we iterate using "for word in text" and modify "word", why doesn't "text" change ?
   The answer has two parts to it:
   (a) Strings are immutable in Python, so whenever you modify a string, you get a new string while the original one remains unmodified. So there is no way to modify string "text" other than by reassigning "text" to a new string.
   (b) Even if strings were mutable, when you iterate over an iterable, you only get *copies* of the elements. So modifying them has no effect on the iterable object.
3. "for elem in range(len(splitstring))" looks clumsy. What is the right way to do this in Python ?

Ok, I made up this question. But the answer is still important. The Pythonic way to do this is:

```
for elem in splitstring:
```

Or if you need the index of each element, then you do this:

```
for index, elem in enumerate(splitstring):
```